# Query other than current database

Tags: mongodb, database

In mongoDB, can I query on DB other than the current DB?
Example: If I have two different databases A and B, and my current database is A (in console), then, can I query on B database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query another database on the same mongod / mongos instance with the [.getSiblingDB()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) method, for example:

```
use A
db.getSiblingDB('B').collection.find(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section about [Opening Additional Connections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/dbshell+Reference) in the manual:

```
db = connect("<host>:<port>/<dbname>")
```

> Open a new database connection. One may have multiple connections within a single shell, however, automatic getLastError reporting by the shell is done for the 'db' variable only.

```
conn = new Mongo("hostname")
```

> Open a connection to a new server. Use getDB() to select a database thereafter.

```
 db = conn.getDB("dbname")
```

> Select a specific database for a connection